# Trouble using modules in typescript

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I'm finally learning Typescript but I am running into a lot of issues. I've got libraries like `jquery` and `pixijs` working because they include type definitions (`npm install --save @types\jquery`, etc).
However, I ran into an issue trying to use `momentjs`. Based on moment's [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) it says to simply use `npm` to install `moment` and import it. However, this is not working. I've tried several different things to get it working but nothing seems to work.

Right now I am using a very basic typescript 2.9/AMD setup. [This project to be specific](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/amd)

Using import causes my entire file to break so that isn't an option. Is there anyway to make `moment` globally available the sameway `PIXI` and `Jquery` are?

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: So, some unknown code causes some unknown issue...

Comment: Using this project as a base https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/amd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two separate aspects to your question:

**1) Global var.**

How to make momentjs available as global variable, without using javascript modules?

Yes, it is possible. See documentation on "Browser" usage. http://momentjs.com/docs/. Just include its minified JS into your HTML from CDN or locally. They also have documentation on using it with requirejs.

Note that if PIXI and JQuery are globally available, you are apparently doing it somehow somewhere in your code already (as script tag, as side effect of AMD module require or something like that). You mentioned that this is because these libs have typescript definitions, but this cannot be the case. Definitions are just definitions - they tell Typescript that, for example, PIXI.Container has addChild method, but do not have actual code for this method.

**2) Type definitions.**

Momentjs provides definitions https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts. You can probably download and use it out of box.

Having said all that, this does not seem like a good approach if you are starting from scratch. Just grab Webpack, install PIXI, jquery and everything else as npm modules, import them with ES6 import in Typescript, and compile everything into 1 minified JS file. After all, you cannot have hundreds of AMD JS modules in your production app, you will have to somehow bundle them at some point anyway.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful and I appreciate your well written response :)